# Is powerline communication secure for a shared building?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have been looking at Ethernet over power to provide network access in another room, as this is on the electrical grid of my building what/are there any security risks with someone sniffing my data? if so are there devices that encrypt the content.

any advise on security issue would be great

Lee

Comment: Why is PoE on the electrical grid?

Comment: Are you confusing "PoE" and "Powerline Ethernet"?

Comment: Do you mean Power-line Ethernet? I can't imagine why PoE would be on the electricals...

Comment: I guess he does, because "using [...] to provide network access" is not what you do with PoE ;)

Comment: Title modified to clarify this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for ethernet over power lines, not PoE (power-over-ethernet which mean using a pair of wires from the ethernet cable to power the device).
I'm using a pair of Devolo at home and they are working well and the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: I just looked a bit of stuff up. You should definitely make sure that the network name the Powerline network uses is individual - some vendors have a generic network name on all of their adapters.

Comment: Of course you should configure it (I don't remember if encryption was by default enabled or not), but it is supported.

Comment: sorry for the mix up I did mean ethernet over power rather than PoE, so if you can set your own names and "network" security id's and you can encrypt the traffic they are ok?

Comment: Yes, that should be reasonably safe.

Comment: Vlad you concern me with your "reasonably safe" any reason for that?

Comment: They are using AES encryption which is enough for practical purposes, barring any bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

Most 'homeplug'-type powerline adaptors use 128-bit AES encryption which should be sufficient, but check the specs of any units you plan to buy before purchasing.